# SQL Server update/insert/delete table records only from stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any way to be sure that a table will be modified (INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE) only by stored procedures  in SQL Server without touching the permissions?

Comment: If you want a table only to be modified by a sproc you need to apply permissions to the table.  In addition, deny any objects / any users / except for the user that needs to run the sproc as well as the sprocs.

Comment: You don't need to grant table permissions to the user running the SP. They will have permissions by nature of running the stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately i don't think there is a way to do it without touching permissions.  The only way I know to do this is to

1. setup a user that can only call SP's (no access to any tables).
2. in each SP, you'll have to impersonate a user that has full access to the tables using "EXECUTE AS" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)
3. Applications then use the new user you created in step one to call SP's.

Comment: You don't have to use execute as.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's what permissions are for.